# UAC Error in SSRS2008 r2

Tags: security, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have installed ssrs 2008 re on one of the servers. It works fine for people who are in same domain as the server is. However, if I try to connect to report server from another domain,

User 'domain1\username' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.

yes, it is a common issue and I have followed the steps on the link below, but Still same error.

[reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sqlexpress/thread/9b5a8763-84ce-46d0-b011-067ad39223d1)

I also tried with FQDN but still same. is there any trick I am missing?

thanks for your help.

Comment: can I ask those who voted this topic to be closed, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the domainname\Domain Users to main folder.

1. Go to Report Manager
2. Click on Folder Settings
3. Grant access to domainname\Domain Users or a specific person

It is pretty straightforward. Please note that you might need to follow the steps on [This link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sqlexpress/thread/9b5a8763-84ce-46d0-b011-067ad39223d1)

hope it helps to others.